# Is there a good reason why new users are not allowed to create new tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation, new-users

I submitted this to the Help Center before I realized that this meta forum existed.  Oops sorry about that.

I was just trying to contribute a question and answer to this SE instance regarding an annoying and confusing UX quirk on my gas utility company's billing web app for residential accounts. But I could not do it because there was no tag for this web app yet and I was not allowed to create the tag. So I was blocked from contributing. I feel like this instance could be a great resource to solve UI problems faster than stupid monopolistic companies who have no incentive to solve them, by making many "bad UI" issues "google-able" to find solutions fast. (for example, find solution much faster than waiting on hold for an hour... zzzzzzzz)  But if its limited to just google apps and similar things and new users cant create tags, then the scope will be very narrow and contribution will be very limited. Most of those apps that have a tag are popular, modern, and actually have competitors in the market -- as a result they are much easier to use on average compared to all the apps that don't have a tag!!  I think this limitation on making new tags is a mistake, because it prevents this SE instance from helping where it is most needed. What do you think?

What alternatives or options exist to make it possible to ask/answer the first question about a given webapp? I don't think it's reasonable to expect users to contact a moderator or post on the meta forum like I have.   IMO there should be a low-friction way to post the first question about a new web app on the Web Applications SE instance. Even if the question has to be moderated and approved 1st, it should at least let you post it.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Possible duplicate [Questions untaggable for low-rep users](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3957/88163)

Comment: Related help article [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score -1):

We already have a tag that might be used when more specific tags doesn't exists for an app like the one that you describe: [website](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website).

It's worthy to mention that questions from new users are sent to a review queue were users that got the corresponding privilege could help to improve the question including creating a new tag.

All users that have a suggestion for a new tag might add a comment to the question suggesting the creation of the new tag. Users that have the required reputation to participate here on Meta also might create a post suggesting the new tag. Before making such post please review the existing tags and previous posts asking for the creation of a new tag.

---

NOTES:

1. Diamond moderators can't customize the Ask page.
2. To suggest a customization of a customizable item of the Ask page create a post here. From [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691)

   > These can only be edited by staff, so the process to get them live is as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298887):
   >
   > - Create a Meta post on the appropriate Meta site, and discuss it with your community.
   > - Once a consensus is reached, a mod should escalate it to the CM team. Generally speaking, the "contact us" form is the best way to go, though a ping in chat can sometimes work too (the most that could happen is we ask you to use the form).
   > - Unless there are any outstanding issues, the CMs should be able to get to it Soon™.
3. Changes to SE features that are not per-site customizable should be requested in Meta SE.

Related posts

- [Questions untaggable for low-rep users](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3957/88163)

Related posts in Meta Stack Exchange

- [Make “how to tag” actually helpful for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263366/289691)
- [How do the tag warnings work in the "Review your question" sidebar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361764/289691)

Related Help Article

- [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

Comment: I think in order for this tag to actually have the intended effect (allowing new users to use the site), the verbiage displayed when the user tries to submit a post without adding a tag needs to recommend adding this tag, **preferrably in bold or otherwise noticeable text**.

  

remember, most web users don't actually read websites/apps.. With the process as it is now, no one is going to be able to find this tag unless they are angry/determined like I was.    You don't want your users angry  :)

Comment: I guess it's probably like this because StackExchange just templates the same app out to all the sub-sites like Web Applications.  If they give you any way of customizing the text on the submission page, even if it's not the "perfect place", I think it should be used to mention the `website` tag & submissions for new apps.   If they don't let you customize the submission page at all, well, then.... that's pretty garbage & they should fix it.

Comment: @forestj Please consider to post you suggestion on Meta.SE. Related Meta.SE post [Make “how to tag” actually helpful for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263366/289691)

Comment: According to this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network

It is possible to customize the error message that is displayed when a user tries to submit a new question without any tags.  So I recommend that the Web Applications SE site set a custom error message. Something like: "Please take a moment to search for any tags which might apply to your question. If you cannot find a tag for the web application you are asking a question about, you may use the `website` tag."

Comment: @forestj Please follow the directions given on the post linked in your comment. (I edited my answer)